# cakephp 3.0 button confirm

Tags: cakephp, button

I'm a noob to CakePhp and wonder if there is a way to make the confirmation for the button to work:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('SetExhibitor', array('action' => 'index', 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'class' => 'form-inline')); ?>
                <table class="table table-bordered data-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>                                
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>                                
                            <td><?php echo $this->Form->button('Hide All', array('type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-small', 'confirm' => 'Are you sure?')); ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**In CakePHP form helper:**

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->button('Hide All', 
    array(
        'type' => 'submit', 
        'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-small',
        'onclick' => 'hideAll()'
    )
); 
?>
```

**js code**

```
<script>
function hideAll() {
    confirm("Are you sure?");
}
</script>
```